# System Monitor with data logging

Tags: monitor, system

Is there some application that allows system monitoring with value logging ?

Most of system monitor application usually shows current system usage (CPU/RAM/HDD/NET etc) with (sometimes) small history log (few minutes back in time).

I looking for application that allows me to check how my system was performing yesterday / week ago / etc.

Something like ex. cacti but without need of starting www server for viewing data.

Answer (score 3):

Please check out our Linux monitoring tool [SeaLion](https://sealion.com). You can use it to schedule any command and then review the history of outputs in the dashboard. Data retention is a minimum of 7 days which can be extended further to 14 days depending on your requirement. You can also plot graphs from the metrics extracted from those outputs with a little bit of python. We are relatively new and looking for any and all kinds of feedback.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of Enterprise [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com/en_us/download.html) to do the centralized log monitoring of your system as well as application components. For personal use free download provides indexing of up to 500MB per day which is very good limit. 
I am using it in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Desktop as well on another laptop(running Ubuntu 15.10 Desktop) for doing the centralized log monitoring, debugging and visualization.

You can download it from [here](https://www.splunk.com/en_us/download/splunk-enterprise.html)

I have installed it under `/opt` and it runs on the default port 8000.
I am using splunk to monitor all the log files under `/var/log` and it looks like this. I can do a free text search on any of the error or string in the log files and it works great.

You can monitor multiple directories also.

Using splunk you can avoid doing a lot of shell scripting and pattern matching and good part everything is provided out of the box.

There are other tools like ELK(ElasticSearch Logstash Kibana) as mentioned [here](https://www.elastic.co/products) and [SiLK](https://lucidworks.com/products/silk/).

Hope this helps.
[image]